# Logicapp Expression to read Dynamic Json path - read child element where parent path may change but hierarchy remaining same

Tags: expression, azure-logic-apps

Hope all well.

I am in need of creating logicapp expression for reading child element in json where name of element & hierarchy remains same but parent name can be changing.

for example : JSON-1 :

```
{
  "root": {
    "abc1": {
      "abc2": [
        {
          "element": "value1",
          "element2": "value"
        },
        {
          "element": "value2",
          "element2": "valu2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

JSON-2 :

```
{
  "root": {
    "xyz1": {
      "xyz2": [
        {
          "element": "value1",
          "element2": "value"
        },
        {
          "element": "value2",
          "element2": "valu2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried these but no luck
approach-1:  @{body('previous-action')?['*']?['*']?['element']
approach-2:  @{body('previous-action')?*?*?['element']

Please let me know if anyone encountered this situation. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to find that converting the JSON to xml (at least in your case) is the simplest solution.  Then when you've done that, you can't use XPath to simply make your selection.

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

In basic terms ...

1. I've defined a variable of type `object` that contains your JSON.
2. I then convert that JSON object to XML using this expression `xml(variables('JSON Object'))`
3. Next, initialize a variable is called `Elements` of type array (given you have multiple of them).  The expression for setting that variable is where the smarts come in.  That expression is ... `xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//element/text()')` and it's getting the inner text of all `element` nodes in the XML.
4. Finally, loop through the results.

If you needed to take it up a level and get the second element then you'd need to change your xpath query to be a lot more generic so you can get the `element2` nodes (and 3, 4, 5, etc. if they existed) in each array as well.

**Note:** *I've stuck to your specific question of looking for `element`.*

**Result**

[image: Resulting Array]

[image: Result]

This definition (which can be loaded directly into your tenant) demonstrates the thinking ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_Each_Element": {
                "actions": {
                    "Set_Element": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "Element",
                            "value": "@{item()}"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "SetVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('Elements')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Element": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_Element": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Element",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_Elements": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_Elements": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Elements",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": "@xpath(xml(variables('XML')), '//element/text()')"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_XML": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_JSON_Object": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "JSON Object",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {
                                "root": {
                                    "abc1": {
                                        "abc2": [
                                            {
                                                "element": "value1",
                                                "element2": "value"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "element": "value2",
                                                "element2": "valu2"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_XML": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "XML",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "@{xml(variables('JSON Object'))}"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_JSON_Object": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "ParameterTest1": {
                "defaultValue": "\"\"",
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time & explanation @Skin. really appreciate.   I am surprised that there is no real alternative with JSON itself, as this is something very common scenario.